# Display PODS Taxonomy in TablePress

Tags: tablepress

I am using this TablePress extension right now: https://code.studioinfinity.org/glen/tablepress-pods . My question is, what parameters can I add to the shortcode, so it lists based on the PODS taxonomy? For example, the category for my custom post type, I only want to list entries for that particular category.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Hey a bit late but you can add the pods statements by putting `pod_` infront of it.
So in your case its

`pods_where:`

Full example:

`[table id=25 pod_name="books" pod_where="category.slug = 'drama'" /]`

Comment: Well, "pod_where" as used in the full example. Accedentially added a "s".

Comment: You should always edit your original answer because readers often don't read the comments.